# What is $Pr(Y=2)$?

Tags: probability

I came across this question that I'm having difficulty in solving.

A binary string of length 4 is chosen uniformly at random. Let $Y$ and $Z$ be random variables so that $Y$ is the total number of $0s$ in the string and $Z$ is the number of $0s$ in the first three bits.

What is $Pr(Y=2)$?

---

**My method so far**

$Pr(Y=2)$ means that the probability of the total number of $0s$ in the string is 2. Hence the strings that have 2 $0s$ should be {$0011,0101,0110,1010,1100$}

Next, I tried to find the sample space for this but I am not sure how to. At first, I thought the sample space would be $2^4$ because each space can only have one of the two numbers 0 and 1, so $\binom2{1}^4$

Therefore, $Pr(Y=2) = \frac{5}{16}$. But upon checking the answer I found out that this is wrong and the answer should be $\frac{3}{8}$

Can anyone help me with this question?

Comment: If you are familiar, see the Binomial Distribution. This was created so that one does not need to individually identify the part of set (especially if the set is big) in favour and end up missing/overlooking items and obtaining incorrect probabilities.

Comment: @UnexpectedConfusion If I were to use the Binomial Distribution method, what would the probability of success be?

Comment: What is the probability of obtaining a $0$? - thats your success **chance**. When you ask what $Pr(Y = 2)$, you are stating whats the probability of choosing $2$  $0$'s, **unordered**, in your sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Missed one situation $1001$ in counting Event $Y=2$, So it should be $6/16 = 3/8$.

Comment: Oh you're right, my bad. Thank you for pointing that out.